# How to get rid of seams on model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

[image: problem]

So, here you can see what I'm stuck with. Im trying to make character with different parts, and because they all are separated, you can see "disconnected seams" I want to smooth these seams, but idk how. Help please.

Comment: Most likely, you will have to merge the separate meshes. If this a sculpt, you can remesh it.

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  If my answer below doesn't answer your question then a few more details could be helpful, such as if these are different objects or a single non-continuous object, if you've checked that all the normals are facing out, or a screenshot showing the topology of the mesh/es.  Also, it's often a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: If you're trying to make character with different parts, it seems very hard to avoid that effect, why do you want to keep different parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by “they all are separated” you mean that they're different objects, then you can't, it's not possible without joining them into a single object.

[image]

In the above screenshot the Suzanne on the left (subdivision applied) is a single object.  The Suzanne on the right is a copy of it with some parts separated into different objects.  Nothing else was done, the topologies are still otherwise identical, but the different objects of the Suzanne on the right can be clearly seen.